# How to select string DataFrame using contains?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

Using spark 2.0, I want to process the [Full MovieLens Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/rounakbanik/the-movies-dataset).

my dataframe contains information about movies :

```
val moviesDF = spark.read.format("csv").option("delimiter",",")
    .option("header","true").option("inferSchema", "true")
    .load("/path/to/movies/")
```

How to select the movies such as the value for the column "tagline" contains the substring "comedy"?

Comment: Your ask is not clear. can you paste the expected output as well. If you want to extract the columns for which column name contains word comedy, something below like will work

val c = df.columns.filter(x => x.contains("comedy"))
df.select(c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter it:

```
val comediesDF = moviesDF.filter("tagline like '%comedy%'")
```

Then you can show the content:

```
comediesDF.show(false)
```

Comment: Thanks sir for answer .I want to get relevant word to comedy also.